# Returning selected table/cell value back to parent window fails when using variable

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to return the value of a clicked-row from a table in a popup window back to the parent window.

It works correctly if I manually specifiy a value in the script.

```
window.opener.document.getElementById('adminticket').value = 12345; // this works fine
```

If I extract the value from the table that was clicked on and output the value that shows the correct value.

```
console.log (selectedticket); // this works fine
```

However, if I put the variable to be returned it does nothing and no console errors.

Full code:

```
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
            
            var table = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
            var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0];
            tbody.onclick = function (e) {
                e = e || window.event;
                var selectedticket = 0;
                var target = e.srcElement || e.target;
                while (target && target.nodeName !== "TR") {
                    target = target.parentNode;
                }
                if (target) {
                    var cells = target.getElementsByTagName("td");
                    selectedticket = (cells[0].innerHTML);
                }
            };                                
            
            console.log (selectedticket); // this works fine
            window.opener.document.getElementById('adminticket').value = 12345; // this works fine
            window.opener.document.getElementById('adminticket').value = document.getElementById(selectedticket); // this doesnt work
            window.opener.document.getElementById('adminticket').value = selectedticket; // this doesnt work
            
            this.window.close();
        });
    });
</script>
```

What am I missing here? Any ideas?

Comment: Seems to be an issue with where the code the variable is accessed -- moving it up side the loop seems to solve the issue

Comment: May be the textbox with id adminticket has type=number and this td value will be interpreted as a string, it is not showing that in the textbox.